# Debian: managing ttyUSB* buffers

Tags: c++, serial-port, debian

I'm working with a (seemingly) finicky USB networking device (zigbee) on Debian 6(ARM). The communications are all via an "AT" command set.  I'm running in to some issues dealig with the IO buffers and am hoping that someone can shed some light on how to best manage this.

Problem: to negotiate the connection(s) between the USB device and the sensors I'm working with I have to follow a sequence of commands. There are typically 3-5: some I just need to know success/fail while other require that I get a return value and use it later. This is all well and good except that the output from the device is often pages of repeated sequences of the same message (typically the return value of an older command). Sometimes it's previous commands, other times it's sequences of the letter "A" (really).

This is why I think I'm mismanaging the IO stream.

How I'm attempting to use it:

### (opening the port - usually /dev/ttyUSB1 )

```
fd = open( pPort, O_RDWR | O_APPEND );
if ( fd == -1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Unable to connect to port: %s", pPort );
    perror( "err: " );
    exit( 0 );
}
else fprintf( stderr, "Connected to %s\n", pPort );

// setup the buffering
struct termios options;

tcgetattr( fd, &options );
cfsetispeed( &options, B19200 );
cfsetospeed( &options, B19200 );

options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;

options.c_lflag &= ~( IXON | IXOFF | IXANY );

tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &options );
```

### (write to the buffer)

```
// clear out any outstanding IO
sleep( 2 );
tcflush( fd, TCIOFLUSH );

int fw = write( fd, cmd, strlen( cmd ) );

if( fw == 0 )
{
    perror( "fwrite err: ");
    exit( 0 );
}

sleep( 2 );
while( 1 )
{
    n = read( fd, &in, 1 );

    instr += in;
    std::size_t found = instr.find( "OK\n" );
    if( found != std::string::npos )
        break;

    static const boost::regex regx( "ERROR: /d{2}" );
    boost::cmatch match;
    if( boost::regex_search( instr.c_str(), match, regx ))
        std::cout << "(5)" << instr << "\n";

}
```

Initially I had hoped to use the 'read from the buffer until it's empty then write' strategy but the buffer is never empty. Or at least it always returns characters when read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serial driver might be doing some processing of the commands - try using `cfmakeraw` to set some of the termios settings in addition to what you have.  Also, make sure `options.c_cc[VMIN] = 1`, that will ensure that you get a byte as soon as it arrives at the port.